# Trouble printing out pattern in array

Tags: java, numbers

I am trying to get the number of pattern to printout from the array but under my number of pattern no pairs were printed out this is an example of what i am trying to get

```
(Array: 2 7 2 3 1 5 7 4 3 6 
Number of patterns: 3)
```

but I do not know what to write from beyond number of patterns

The code:

```
public class FindIt {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int Sum = 0;
        int[] InsertNumbers = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Sample output #1:");
        System.out.print("Array: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            InsertNumbers[i]=(int)(Math.random()*10)+1;
            System.out.print(InsertNumbers[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Array: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            ComputePattern(InsertNumbers, Sum);
            System.out.print(InsertNumbers[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Number of patterns: ");

    }
    public static void ComputePattern(int[] InsertNumbers, int Sum)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            InsertNumbers[i] = Sum;
            Sum = Sum + Sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "pattern pair"?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to understand your code but here is what I can tell you.
You have managed to get to ask the user input but I feel that the following would be better.

Instead, try having two arrays, one which the user can input 10 integers, and the other array with the sum of the pairs, hence an array containing 5 integers.

With the help of a For Loop and a formula, you can use it to get the 2 consecutive values. The first formula being x*2, the second being (x*2)+1.
With x being 0 in the for loop, and loop it for 5 times.

Afterwards, you get the values of the x*2 and the (x*2)+1 in the array, and sum them together.

Then with the sum, you can then use it to calculate the count of patterns.

Suggestion : Try to be consistent with your println and print. It is quite confusing and I am not quite sure as to why you have set println for certain text and print for the rest.

Answer (score -1):

No patterns were printed because you have no print statements after you print `Number of patterns`.